Decimals are not stored in a numeric variable
I’m just starting with COBOL, and I’m testing storing and displaying values on the screen. When the user enters the value 10.5 in the terminal, the program stores it as 10.0. I’m using the GnuCOBOL compiler.
Why doesn’t it save the value 10.5? Thank you.
The code is this:
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. CALC1000.

   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.

   DATA DIVISION.
   FILE SECTION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   77  INTEREST-RATE          PIC 9(2)V9.

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   DISPLAY "INTEREST-RATE? "
   ACCEPT INTEREST-RATE.
   DISPLAY "INTEREST-RATE : " INTEREST-RATE.
   STOP RUN.



Your interest rate picture is 99V9.  You typed 99.9  What you typed is not the same as your interest rate picture.  Either type 105 or change your picture and move your 99.9 to a separate 99V9 field.

If I type 105 the programme stores 05

I don’t understand why it displayed the .0part. It should have just displayed 10. surely?

There is a complete thread in this link (someone has written a "NUMCHECK.cbl" routine to make a complex validation number):
From this thread there is a very simple approach in the last comment, that I tested and it works fine:
WORKING STORAGE SECTION.
01 amount pic x(9).
01 edit-amount pic -99999.99.
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
DISPLAY 'AMOUNT? --> '
accept amount.
move amount to edit-amount.
DISPLAY 'edit-amount = ' edit-amount. 

I hope it helps you.
